# Return sorted unique values from array, but if count is equal, return values in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, unique

I am creating a function that takes in an array of unsorted integers and returns an array of the unique integers, sorted by frequency. However, if the integers have the same frequency, they will be returned in the original order of the input array. Here is my current function:

```
function uniqueUnionSorted(arr) {
  counter = {};
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] in counter) {
      counter[arr[i]] ++;
    } else {
      counter[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  sortedStrings = Object.keys(counter).sort(function(a,b) {
    return counter[b] - counter[a]
  });
  var sortedNumbers = sortedStrings.map(Number);
  return sortedNumbers;
}
```

So for an array like this:

```
arr = [1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4]
```

the function should return:

```
[1,2,3,5,4]
```

However, my function is sorting the 5 and 4 and is returning:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this reordering is that object properties that are numerical will come out ordered when using `Object.keys()`.

Instead of defining `counter` as an object, use a `Map`, which will retain the insertion order:

```js
function uniqueUnionSorted(arr) {
  var counter = new Map();
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    counter.set(arr[i], (counter.get(arr[i]) || 0) + 1);
  }
  // Spreading the Map will produce an array of pairs
  var sortedNumbers = [...counter].sort(function(a,b) {
    return b[1] - a[1]; // sort by count
  }).map(a => a[0]); // only keep the values, not the counts
  return sortedNumbers; // Map keys retain original type, so they remain numeric
}

arr = [1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4]

console.log(uniqueUnionSorted(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

In counter object we can also save lowest index of each element so we can keep elements with lower index earlier in sorted array.

```js
function uniqueUnionSorted(arr) {
  counter = {};
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
if (arr[i] in counter) {
  counter[arr[i]].count ++;
} else {
  counter[arr[i]] = {'count' : 1, 'index' : i}; //save lowest index of element
}
  }
  sortedStrings = Object.keys(counter).sort(function(a,b) {
    return counter[b].count - counter[a].count || counter[a].index - counter[b].index;
  });
  var sortedNumbers = sortedStrings.map(Number);
  return sortedNumbers;
}

console.log(uniqueUnionSorted([1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4]));
```

Comment: Good solution. You could shorten the sort callback return expression to: `return counter[b].count - counter[a].count || counter[a].index - counter[b].index;`

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/anLrwwfa/4/

Here's another way you could do this using a Set object, an object to store frequency, and the original array to keep the origin intact. It's a bit longer than the current popular answer but I was in the midst of writing it, so I figured I would throw my hat in the ring.

```
function sortArr(arr) {
  let uniqueValues = new Set();
  let frequencies = new Object();
//add values to set object
  arr.map((val) => uniqueValues.add(val));

//get frequencies of values
  for (let val of uniqueValues) {
    frequencies[val] = 0;
  }
  arr.map((val) => frequencies[val]++);

//sort by frequency, then sort by original placement in array
 let sorted_arr = Array.from(uniqueValues).sort((a, b) => {
    return frequencies[a] - frequencies[b];
  }).sort((a, b) => {
      return (frequencies[a] === frequencies[b]) ?
        Array.from(uniqueValues).indexOf(a) - Array.from(uniqueValues).indexOf(b) :
        b;
    });
//return array
    return sorted_arr;
  };

sortArr([1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4]);  //1,2,3,5,4
```

**EDIT**
optimized code a bit

Answer (score 0):

May add an additional condition to actually sort after the original array index if the frequency is equal:

```
sortedStrings = Object.keys(counter).sort(function(a,b) {
  return counter[b] - counter[a] || arr.indexOf(+a)-arr.indexOf(+b)
 });
```

http://jsbin.com/zewulanozo/edit?console

Comment: I did not downvote, but I would mention that the use of `indexOf`, inside the `sort` callback, makes the `sort` run in *O(n²logn)* instead of *O(nlogn)*.

Comment: @trincot worst case only. In the upper example this happens once, and this still answers the question...

Comment: Indeed, I agree.